# What is the relationship between char *, memory addresses, and ASCII code?

Tags: for-loop, pointers, ascii

Why is my code behaving this way when I dereference *str + i? I know that, if I were going to try to print each character of the string one-by-one, I would have done str[i] rather than *str + i, but I wanted to see what happened here.

Is the computer recognizing that 'A' is the first letter, finding the memory location of 'A', and then just going up through the ASCII table? It almost seems like there is just *one* place in the computer in which the letter 'A' is stored, I found it, and then because a char is one byte it just went through the rest of the ASCII table on the for loop.

Thank you!

input:

```
char *str1 = "Abc";

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    printf("letter: %c - ", *str1 + i);
    printf("memory address: %p", &str1 + i);
    printf("\n");
}
```

output:

```
letter: A - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9510
letter: B - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9518
letter: C - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9520
letter: D - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9528
letter: E - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9530
letter: F - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9538
letter: G - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9540
letter: H - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9548
letter: I - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9550
letter: J - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9558
letter: K - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9560
letter: L - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9568
letter: M - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9570
letter: N - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9578
letter: O - memory address: 0x7ffea8ea9580
```

etc. etc. etc.

Comment: It just takes `*str1`, which is always `'A'`, and adds `i` to it.  You end up with the `i`th letter following `A`.  No other byte in memory is used in any way.

Comment: Is *str1 always the same as 'A' because, when I initialized my string as 'Abc', the only thing that the pointer is looking at is 'A'? Obviously 'A' has a value on the ASCII table so - when I dereference the pointer with *str1 - and then add i, that is where I am getting this run through the ASCII table. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
char *str1 = "ABC";
```

memory looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | \0|
+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
+---+
|   | str1
+---+
```

With that in mind, what does

```
*str + i
```

do? Well, C interprets this to mean "give me the character pointed at by `str`, then add `i` to it." Since `str1` points to the first character of the string, the value of `*str` is `'A'`. Adding `i` to `'A'` then starts advancing through the characters of the alphabet sequentially, which is why you see `A`, then `B`, then `C`, etc.

On the other hand, when you write

```
&str1 + i
```

C interprets this to mean "give me the address of the variable `str1`, then shift forward `i` positions." So, for example, `&str1 + 0` is the address of the `str1` pointer, then `&str1 + 1` is the memory address of where a `char*` one position past `str1` would be, etc. But none of those addresses, other than `&str1 + 0`, actually represents anything.

If you want to see the addresses of the *array elements*, just write `str1 + i`. That means "go where `str1` points, then advance forward `i` positions."